# Как изменять скорость transition css или scss в зависимости от ширены элемента?

Tags: css-animation, sass, scss, transition

Чем больше элемент тем медленнее анимация. Я использую React и scss. Варианты были разные функция calc(), transition-timing-function, даже через React пробовал. Если описывать проблему подробней то при наведении на кнопку ::after должен делать анимацию. Но В моем проекте кнопки разные и хотелось бы как-то оптимизировать. Чтобы оно автоматически определяло время анимации.

Comment: Где код html и css?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.